# How to disable scrolling functionality on wheel event QGraphicsView Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have a graphics view and i have set my own function for scrolling by hand drag when the user presses control and mouse clicks.

I have removed the scroll bars but the mouse wheel will still scroll and even scroll past the image that's being displayed in the `qGraphicsView` showing blank (white) space which my hand drag doesn't.

How do i make it so wheel just straight up does nothing at all?

I know there is a function I can just put in my code without a derived class because I asked this once before and got the right answer but the answer was removed and i hadn't saved the code :(

The below code does nothing even close to the expected functionality, on start up I get the mouse still doing something message and then all clicks and wheel events everything just displays that second message ... so yea not working

```
bool GUI::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
 {
     if (object == ui->graphicsView && event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneWheel)
     {
         std::cout << "Wheel Blocked";
         return true;
     }
     std::cout << "Mouse Wheel still doing something";
     return false;
 }
```

and then this code to install the filter

```
ui->graphicsView->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: Somebody already gave the right answer in the meantime and I spent an upvote. Btw. from your code sample I don't see which object's mouseEvent() you are overwriting. As you say you do not have a derived class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install an [eventfilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) and filter for

```
QEvent::GraphicsSceneWheel
```

Create something like this in your app

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == ui->graphicsView->viewport() && event->type() == QEvent::Wheel) {
        qDebug() << "SCroll";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and install to your widget.

```
yourwidget->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
```

Edit: 
I thought it should work with QEvent::GraphicsSceneWheel. If anyone knows why works with Wheel, please, explain

Comment: gives this error `overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'QObject::eventFilter' `

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter  This is the function you should be overloading, Also, note that in that example they return parent method to keep flow.

Comment: This DOES work. Paste your code, so. We can spot what you're doing wrong

Comment: if you can see where it differs from yours and let me know your thoughts that would be great

Comment: Try installing in viewport (second line from second block of code )

Comment: Ok, tried at home. Your problem is: You need to install it in viewport, then, **compare object with viewport** too, not the view. And Event is QEvent::Wheel

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can to modify QGraphicsView using inheritance

```
class MyCustomGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{

virtual void    wheelEvent ( QWheelEvent * event )
{
//here you can modify wheel-event
}

}
```

It is easy way, because qt-designer can associate GraphicsView element on your form with your inherited class

Comment: OP explicit says "without a derived class"