# QWheelEvent::ignore() doesn't work in promoted QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, events, mousewheel

I promote my `QLineEdit` to a custom widget and trying to reimplement mouse event handlers. I need to handle all mouse events except `mouseDoubleClickEvent()` by parent of my `QLineEdit`-based widget (parent is a custom scrollable area). All works well except `wheelEvent()`. `QLineEdit` is still handle mouse wheel and parent is still not.
Here is my promoted `QLineEdit`:

```
HeightLineEdit::HeightLineEdit(QWidget* parent) :
QLineEdit(parent)
{
    this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
}

void HeightLineEdit::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    event->ignore();
}

void HeightLineEdit::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    event->ignore();
}

void HeightLineEdit::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    event->ignore();
}

void HeightLineEdit::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    this->setFocus();
    this->selectAll();
}

void HeightLineEdit::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)
{
    event->ignore();
}
```

Comment: Try to install event filter in parent: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279003/how-to-disable-scrolling-functionality-on-wheel-event-qgraphicsview-qt-c

Comment: Parent is already have an event filter and wheel works fine at free parent space. I need parent to handle wheel for scrolling even if it overlaps with child widget.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`QWheelEvent` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwheelevent.html): "Wheel events are sent to the widget under the mouse cursor, but if that widget does not handle the event they are sent to the focus widget."

If you want the parent to handle them for the child widget, you can either install an [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) on the child widget, or you could directly call a method on the parent widget from the child's `wheelEvent` method.

Comment: Maybe I do not fully understand your suggestion with an event filter on the child widget. It works as well as handler functions in my case. In event filter I just list all `QEvent` types in `switch{}` and call `QEvent::ignore()` where necessary. Same effect.

Comment: I removed the probably confusing part, which was meant only for the second suggestion, but not very relevant information for the answer anyhow.